# 404 ao acessar via route edit

Tags: php, laravel, framework

minha viewer

```
@extends('tamplate.menu')
```

@section('conteudo')

## Produtos

Novo item
            
              
                Descricão
                Preço
                Quantidade
                Data de cadastro
              
            
            
        @forelse($produtos as $produto)
          
            {{$produto->descricao}}
            {{$produto->valor_unit.'R$'}}
             {{$produto->quantidade}}
            {{$produto->data_cad}}
                Editar
                @empty

nenhum produto cadastrado

@endforelse
        
      
    
@endsection

minhas rotas 
   Route::group(['prefix'=>'produto'],function(){
    //Route::get('produto','ProdutoController@create');
        Route::resource('/','ControllerProduto');
        //Route::get('edit/{{id}}','ControllerProduto@edit');
        //Route::get('/edit/{id}','ProdutoController@edit');
        //Route::match(['get','post'],'/update/{id}','ProdutoController@update');
    //Route::get('/produto','ProdutoController@index');
});

Meu controller
`

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Requests\ProdutoStoreFormRequest;
use App\Produto;

class ControllerProduto extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    private $produto;

```
public function __construct(Produto $produto){
    $this->produto = $produto;
}
public function index()
{
    $produtos = $this->produto->all();

    return view('produtos.exibe_produtos',compact('produtos'));
}

/**
 * Show the form for creating a new resource.
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function create()
{
      return view('produtos.formulario');
}

/**
 * Store a newly created resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function store(Request $request)
{
     $dados = $request->all();
    if($dados['data_cad'] == ''){
        $dados['data_cad'] = '2015-10-10';
    }


    $insert = $this->produto->create($dados);
    /*$validate = validator($dados,$this->produto->rules,$messages);
    if( $validate->fails()){
        return redirect()->back()
                         ->withErrors($validate)
                         ->withInput();
    }else{

    }
    //$this->validate($request, $this->produto->rules);
    $insert = $this->produto->create($dados);


    */


        return redirect('produto');

}

/**
 * Display the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function show($id)
{
    //return 'ola';
}

/**
 * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function edit($id)
{
    return 'teste';
}

/**
 * Update the specified resource in storage.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    //
}

/**
 * Remove the specified resource from storage.
 *
 * @param  int  $id
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function destroy($id)
{
    //
}
```

}
`Ao utilizar`href="{{ route('edit',1)}}"`em minha`view`para redirecionar ao método`edit`, a página não é encontrada.

Utilizando o `href="{{route('create')}}"`, funciona corretamente.

[image: aqui esta o print do meu codigo[![][1][1]]

Comment: Poste seu código, nem todo mundo consegue abrir as imagem.

Comment: Sou novo nesse forum, não sei como funciona exatamente

Answer (score 0):

pra utilizar o método RESOURCE na rota, não coloca dentro do prefix.

***Route::resource('produto','ControllerProduto');***

utiliza isso fora do prefix e testa!